# Do not wrap grid_elements content object, OR, only wrap children of grid_elements in Typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am building a responsive front-end using Typo3 & the gridelements extension. I want to wrap each individual content element inside of a gridelement column in a wrapper, like this:

```
  <div class="row"> <-- wrap around whole gridelements content element
    <div class="column size2"> <-- wrap around gridelements column
     <div class="module> <-- wrap around content inside of gridelement column
       CONTENT
     </div>
     <div class="module>
       CONTENT
     </div>
    </div>   
  </div>
```

If I go and put a `div class="module"` wrap around all ordinary content elements, then it gets wrapped TWICE- once around the gridelements "element", and once around each child content element:

```
  <div class="module"> <-- WRONG!
   <div class="row"> <-- wrap around whole gridelements content element
    <div class="column size2"> <-- wrap around gridelements column
     <div class="module> <-- wrap around content inside of gridelement column
       CONTENT
     </div>
     <div class="module>
       CONTENT
     </div>
    </div>   
  </div>
 </div>
```

I guess that I can either a) wrap all content elements with `div class="module"`, EXCEPT for content element of type gridelements, OR b) wrap children of gridelements with `div class="module"`. What would be the best approach, and what would the TypoScript for either of these options look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure, but i think this is what you are looking for.

```
# the grid element uid
1 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
1 {
  columns {
    # colPos ID
    10 < .default
    10.wrap = <div class="row">|</div>

    # this adds the value "module" as class and wraps a content element
    # which is inside this grid. (like a replace for csc-default)
    default.renderObj.20 {
     stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.20.10.value = module
   }
  }
}
```

maybe there is a better solution. if so, let me know

## EDIT:

hmm, i slightly misunderstood the whole thing, so i changed a bit :P